# Kafka consumer is getting out of active group and not able to consume ant message further

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am using spring kafka to implement kafka listener with default properties. I have noticed that with some failure eg: broker not available or any internal call failure after consuming message, it stops consuming messages and I can see attached error while commiting previous consumed message.

How can we make our kafka consumer to reconnect to group and start consuming message without pod restart in kubernetes?
As currently when we restart our kubernetes pod the kafka consumer starts listening to message from last committed offset.

[image: screenshot showing error message]

Comment: what is your settings for reconnect.backoff.ms ?

Comment: I am not overriding these properties for reconnect. It is used as default. But here I'm asking for reconnection possibilities after consumer is out of active group which stops it to consume message.